# Can putting an SSD on a hard drive make it overheat?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, temperature, overheating

So today I bought a 2 TB hard drive and a 240 GB SSD, and I have my old ( about ) 470 GB hard drive, since I had no bracket for the SSD I could only install my 2 TB hard drive in the slot, and so now the new 2 TB is at the bottom, the old hard drive is in the middle and my SSD isn't properly installed, it just physically lays on top of the old drive, actually touching it.

My question is, can it cause problems to the SSD drive? Can it make it overheat or something like that because of the direct physical contact with the old one or can I give up my concerns?

Comment: There needs to be an air gap between the drives, so yes it can make the SSD overheat laying on top of the HDD.

Comment: Also if you were to cover the pin hole that most drives have, then most definitely you would have problems

Comment: Its worth pointing out that those holes are for pressure equalisation and are often recessed or not on the top of the drive.  They are not used for cooling.

Answer (score 2):

Unless temperatures in your case get extremely hot, this should be fine in practice but no one can give you guarantees without more knowledge of your case, airflow, system power draw.

Surprisingly,  as far as SSDs go, warmer operating temps put less stress on them - so this could be a good thing for the SSD - see https://www.anandtech.com/show/9248/the-truth-about-ssd-data-retention - as a rule of thumb the more energy efficient the drive the cooler the ideal - so faster drives are a better fit in your environment.

When it comes to hard drives there is a very weak correlation between temperature and reliability - see https://www.backblaze.com/blog/hard-drive-temperature-does-it-matter/

With respect of hard disks it's not uncommon to have them pretty much touching, although many people would choose to have fans blowing across them (generally sucking/air into case and over drives - it's no good circulating air round and round - generally you want air to follow a path through the system )

Of course, heat does put stress on componentry, so doing this could reduce the life of the drives - the question is does it matter if they last 5 instead of 6 years.

Answer (score 1):

I did the same thing for years with no problem until I finally bought a proper bracket to mount it.  I don't think you need to be worried.